# How do I read a file in parts with NAudio?

Tags: c#, buffer, naudio

I am fairly new to C# and Mark's library NAudio. So I've tried learning by myself and I've come up with an basic audio player. But I have a problem.

When trying to load big files in the player the app freezes for 2-10 seconds while loading the entire file (I suppose). This is my code for reading the file:

```
if (target.EndsWith("mp3") || target.EndsWith("Mp3") || target.EndsWith("MP3"))
        {
            NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcm = NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(target));
            stream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);
        }
```

All I really want is to read the file in parts. Like a buffer. Read 10 seconds from the HDD to RAM memory, then after those 10 seconds run out, read the next 10 seconds, and so on. I think this should resolve the freeze issue I have with large files.

Comment: This is not the answer to your question but you can test for mp3 with `if (target.Upper().EndsWith("MP3"))`.

Comment: Please note you don't need WaveFormatConversionStream or BlockAlignReductionStream. Where did you see the code sample that includes these?

Comment: Hi! Than you for you answers. @MarkHeath - I've followed this tutorial series by Giawa - [Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ij2vqgprU0). The code is from this video, and the actual code I used it's shown @2:15.

Comment: OK, that demo relates to NAudio 1.3. A lot has changed since

Comment: Oh, I've might overlooked that bit. I'll search some newer tutorials, or I'll be trying to do a new script based on the examples provided from the codeplex site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the delay is that `Mp3FileReader` creates a table of contents to allow it to determine the file length and to enable quicker repositioning. You could try using `MediaFoundationReader` instead which would be quicker, but won't work on Windows XP.

Comment: The `MediaFoundationRader` works like it shoud, the file loads a lot quicker (almost instantaneously). Thank you for the quick answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

all programs have delay to load big files. this is depended to client computer speed.
but you can use backgroundWorker in your program and show a loading animation on your application Form during the file loading.

add backgroundWorker tool on your form

use this code on open button click:

```
backgroundWorker_name.RunWorkerAsync();
```

and put your code to the DoWork event

```
private void backgroundWorker_name_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll surely try this. But I want to understand how audio players, like foobar2000, VLC or WinAmp seem to load the file instantly with no big CPU and HDD effort. I will test my player, along with the code you provide on a Solid State Drive to see how it affects the loading times.